# Issue with Jquery DaterangePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am trying to implement Jquery DateRangePicker in asp.net mvc application.
In `<head>` section I have added below

```
<!-- Include dependencies -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" />

<!-- Include date range picker plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/1/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/1/daterangepicker-bs3.css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.daterangepicker.js"></script>
```

And on my view page I have written

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('input[name="daterange"]').dateRangePicker();
});
```

At runtime it gives me error "Object doesn't support property or method 'dateRangePicker'"

I have tried daterangepicker as well but getting same error , please help

Comment: Make sure the main jquery file is loaded before you make a call to `.dateRangePicker`

Comment: Looks like this plugin is actually for Bootstrap, but you do not appear to be loading the Bootstrap JS file. It also looks like you are loading two different datepicker plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
</head>

<input type="text" name="datetimes" />

<script>
  
$(function() {
  $('input[name="datetimes"]').daterangepicker();
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```